# Two fields validation

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <form class="form-horizontal cmxform" id="validateForm" method="get" action="../../course_controller" onsubmit="return validate();" autocomplete="off">


                    <input type="text" id="course_name" name="course_name"  placeholder="Enter Course Name..." class="row-fluid" required onkeyup="javaScript:return validate_course_name();">
                 <label id="course_name_info"  style="color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);font-size:13px">
                      </label>

                    <input type="text" id="course_desc" name="course_desc"  placeholder="Enter Course Name..." class="row-fluid" required onkeyup="javaScript:return validate_course_desc();">
                 <label id="course_desc_info"  style="color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);font-size:13px">
                      </label>


                    <button type="submit" name="user_action" value="add" class="btn btn-primary"  >Save</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>



              </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /**** Specific JS for this page ****/

  //Validation things




function validate_course_name(){

     var TCode = document.getElementById('course_name').value;
        if( /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode ) ) {

            document.getElementById('course_name_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
           return false;
        }
        else
            {
             document.getElementById('course_name_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
            return true; 
            }


    }

function validate_course_desc(){

     var TCode = document.getElementById('course_desc').value;
        if( /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode ) ) {

            document.getElementById('course_desc_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
           return false;
        }
        else
            {
             document.getElementById('course_desc_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
            return true; 
            }


    }
function validate(){


    return validate_course_name();

    return validate_course_desc();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So this the code ...I am applying alpha numeric validation on two field but the problem is if i give first input field valid input and second invalid form get submitted  where am i doing it wrong? ...i am very new to this web so any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: your `validate()` is incorrect. if name validation succeeds, the first return statement executes and returns from the method. Never gets the chance to run the second validation. Do something like "if first validation is successful, then invoke the second one."

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Fine! Just to be different =)

One line, should validate both fields regardless if the `validate_course_name()` returns `false`.

**JSFiddle:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/fVqTY/3/

```
function validate()
{
    return (validate_course_name() * validate_course_desc()) == true;
}
```

Let `false` = 0, `true` = 1. Now do the math :)

Comment: However this won't show both error messages if both fields are incorrect, so I give my +1 to PSR

Comment: @Paulpro I'll call it a "feature". =P

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate(){    

    var value1 = validate_course_name();

    var value2 = validate_course_desc();

   if(value1 == true && value2 == true)
     return true;
   else
     return false
}
```

or You can use

```
function validate(){

var validate = true;
 var TCode = document.getElementById('course_name').value;
 var TCode1 = document.getElementById('course_desc').value;
    if(! /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode ) ) {
        document.getElementById('course_name_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
        validate = false;
    }
     if(! /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode1 ) ) {
        document.getElementById('course_name_info').innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
        validate = false;
    }
    return validate;



}
```

and then call this function directly

Comment: @user2137186 did you understand the problem

Comment: +1 For showing the first way of doing it. Each does a slightly different thing. Your first version will validate both fields and show the message for each, while the second one will not show the message for the descripti
on if the coure name is invalid.

Comment: @user2137186 you can use the first code to show two validation error messgaes

Comment: @PSR is there specifically a reason for the `if(validate == false)` at the end there?

Comment: Yes if any one of the validation fails\ then it will return false

Comment: @PSR why not just return `validate` instead?

Answer (score 1):

In this function, You should return only once. So what happens here is that when `validate_course_name()` gets executed, control is already returned to the calling routine. `validate_course_desc()` line won't execute.

```
function validate(){


    return validate_course_name();

    return validate_course_desc();

}
```

**You should do this:**

```
function validate(){


        var bol1 = validate_course_name();

        var bol2 = validate_course_desc();

if(bol1 == true && bol2 == true)
return true;
else
return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the function validate()

```
function validate()
{


    if(validate_course_name()  && validate_course_desc())
    {
       return true;
    } 

    return false;

}
```

Once return statement is executed in a function, other statements that are following return statement does not work.

Therefore every time, validate_course_name() function is called , a bool value is returned and the function validate_course_desc() is not even called/executed.

Therefore, the validate function returns true if validate_course_name() is true and false if validate_course_name() return false.Hence , When you  give first field valid input and second invalid, form get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your validate method as given below will return as soon as the first validate method (`validate_course_name`) is called so it will not execute the `validate_course_desc` method.

```
function validate(){
    return validate_course_name();
    return validate_course_desc();
}
```

The solution is to execute both the validate method and summarise them to create the return value as given in the above answers

Answer (score 0):

the validation of both inputfields is the same, so you can make one validation function which takes an element-id as parameter:

```
function validateInputfield(id){

     var TCode = document.getElementById(id).value;
     if( /[^a-zA-Z1-9 _-]/.test( TCode ) ) {
         document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Please Enter Only Alphanumeric or _,-,' ' ";
         return false;
     } else {
         return true; 
     }
}
```

Then you can use the function `validate()` to check if both inputfields are valid:

```
function validate() {

    if (validateInputfield('course_desc_info') == true &&
        validateInputfield('course_name_info') == true) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```